# Upgraded from CentOS 6.4 -> 6.5 and now permissions do not seem to work properly?

Tags: centos, permissions, upgrade

I allow my non-root user the ability to view my `nginx` access.log.  I upgraded from `CentOS 6.4` to `6.5` and now my user cannot view this file but the permissions still look correct.

I removed and readded my user to the `nginx` group....

Am I missing something obvious?  Bleh, the user is `nginx` and the group is `adm` right?  that is probably what Im missing.....  Just needed to type it out.

```
[09:46 AM] brian web>ll
-rw-r-----. 1 nginx adm 6393 Dec  4 09:23 access.log
-rw-r-----. 1 nginx adm    0 Dec  4 03:12 error.log    

[09:46 AM] brian web> groups brian
brian : wheel brian nginx

[09:47 AM] brian web> cat access.log
cat: access.log: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `brian` is a `nginx` group member, but `nginx` group does not have any permission on your acces log file. Add `brian` to the `adm` group.